# Height of two outer divs relative to inner one

Tags: html, height

I have 3 divs:

```
<div style="float:left; background-color:#000; width:300px;" ></div>
<div style="float:left; color:#000; width:600px;" >Text</div>
<div style="float:left; background-color:#000; width:300px;" ></div>
```

The Text of the inner one is loaded dynamically and the height of the div should wrap the text. This is working fine, but I also want the two outer divs which are some kind of placeholder to have the same height as the middle one. How can i accomplish this?

My first thought was, that i wrap all 3 divs in another div and inherit the height of the 3 divs, because the wrapping div should have the same height as the one with the text. But I failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t need to support older browsers, use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). You probably don’t want to use float for basic layout at all.